# Laravel 5: validate token outside VerifyCsrfToken

Tags: php, security, laravel, controller, laravel-5

I need to verify Laravel 5 token, outside `VerifyCsrfToken` class,

is there way to call `VerifyCsrfToken->handle` from `Controller`

or verify them using any different way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

return (session('_token') == $variableYouNeedToCheck);

Comment: `$request` is not a defined varialbe in Controllers

Comment: answer updeted. btw, can u explain the case when u need this check?

Answer (score 2):

See the code below for a working simple code

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
class MyController extends Controller {

      public function getIndex(Request $request)
         if(hash_equals(request->get('myCSRFTokenFromMyFormOrAjax'), Session::token())){
             // token not matches please 
             //redirect or stop the application here 
         }
      }
 }
```

I used [hash_equals()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) for security reasons were sometimes hashes may be the same for different values

If you didn't understand the code above read about [Type hinting](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-middleware-handle-method-type-hinting-request)

Also note that using [Laravel5.0](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/) it's better to create a middlewere to gain control on your code and Don't repeate a a peace of code everywhere [Read this Worndefull article](http://engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/csrf-protection-with-ajax-and-laravel)

Comment: -1 Don't use `!=` to compare hashes, use at *least* `!==` but for security purposes, you definitely want `StringUtils::equals()`

Comment: thanks for the adding i have read about it  [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) and now i got the securty proplem .

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [M0rtiis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31763311/2224584), but with timing-safe comparison:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\StringUtils;
// ...
return StringUtils::equals(session('_token'), $variableYouNeedToCheck);
```

Don't use `==` to compare strings, use something equivalent to PHP 5.6's [`hash_equals()`](https://secure.php.net/hash_equals)